# JBOSS explode war file on build (hot deployment)

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, jboss

The last Java project I was on used Tomcat as the server my new Java project is using JBOSS.

I am a front-end designer that needs to make frequent and rapid changes to JSP, HTML, CSS and JS files.  Here is a rundown of what is happening...

In Tomcat, when an app is deployed into the webapps directory, it is automatically exploded.  From there I can stop the server, create symbolic links pointing from the webapps/myapp directory to my GIT repository, ~/somedir/myapp and then restart tomcat.  This way I am always working on my local repository and when I make a change in my IDE then go to the browser and refresh, the changes are there instantly.

In JBOSS, things are a bit different.  When an app is deployed into the standalone/deployments directory, it remains compressed as a .war file.

I have tried expanding the .war file manually and renaming the folder to myapp.war and that seemed to work, however, JBOSS still re-deployed the app once it noticed there was a change to one of the files, which kinda defeats the purpose.

I have been searching for a couple of days now before asking this question as a last resort.

Does anyone happen to know of a way to accomplish in JBOSS what I was able to accomplish in Tomcat?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply! 
Jboss 7.1.1

Comment: Have you tried: https://community.jboss.org/thread/202446

Comment: Yes, I have.  No luck.  I was able to get expanding the .war file and renaming the folder to myapp.war, but when I tried using the symlinks, I found out that Jboss 7.x doesn't support symlinks :|